# What is ZRangeValid means

Tags: asp.net, adodb

This code is to read an excel file, what is ZRangeValid means and what is rs.fields(0).value referring to? Please explain my two questions

```js
 var strConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + strXLPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\";";

        var conn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");


        conn.open(strConnString, "", "");

        var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

        var rsrowCount = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
        rs = conn.execute("select * from ZRangeValid");
        if (rs.fields(0).value != 'YES') {
            alert(strXLPath + " requested numbers spreadsheet is not valid.\nPlease validate the spreadsheet data and retry.")
            rs = null;
            rsSheet = null;
            conn.close();
            conn = null;
            return false

        }
```